# Chart js plugin annotation not working in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line in my chart js with annotations plugin but it doesn't seem to work.

My chartjs version is 2.9.4 so i had to install with this command: npm install chartjs-plugin-annotation@0.5.7 --save

After importing, if i tried registering it with `Chart.register(annotationPlugin)` it returned:

TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.Chart.register is not a function

So after searching online i read that i could do:

`Chart.plugins.register(AnnotationPlugin)` and it seemed to work.

Here's my chart configuration:

```
import BarChart from '../Charts/BarChart'
import DetailsComponent from './Reusable/Details'
import AnnotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
import Chart from 'chart.js';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      aud2Chart: {
    chartdata: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Valor da nota",
          fill: false,
          tension: false,
          pointRadius: 5,
          pointHitRadius: 10,
          pointHoverRadius: 10,
          backgroundColor: "#556aff",
          data: [],
          pointBackgroundColor: []
        },
      ],
    },  
    options: {
    annotation: {
        annotations: [{
            id: 'a-line-1',
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'horizontal',
            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
            value: '15000',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 2,
        }]
    },
      legend: {
        onClick: null
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        callbacks: {
          label(vars){
            let float = parseFloat(vars.value).toFixed(2)
            let parts = float.toString().split(".")
            parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ")
            let formatted = parts.join(".").replace('.', ',')

            if(vars.datasetIndex == 0){  
              return 'Valor total da nota fiscal: ' + formatted
              } else { 
              return 'Média deste momento: ' + formatted
            }
          }
        }
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
    },
  },
...
```

The data of the graph isn't in the code because it comes from the api.

There are no errors returned in console.

I tried one of the solutions i found that was wrapping the annotation object inside a plugin{} object but it didn't work.

If it matters, i'm using vue-chartjs also, so i'm importing this component to show the graph:

```
<script>
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  props: ["chartdata", "options"],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options);
  },
};
</script>
```

Here's some of my settings:

chart js version: 2.9.4
annotations plugin version: 0.5.7
vue-chartjs version: 3.5.1

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use v3 syntax while using v2, to register plugins in V2 you need to type it like so:

```js
import AnnotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

Chart.plugins.register(AnnotationPlugin)
```

Comment: That's what i wrote though

Comment: mb, read only to your chart.register line and saw code block underneath, might want to remove it since its uneccesarry info